# Syntax error at input 'end of line without line continuation'

Tags: import, syntax-error, end-of-line, line-continuation

The code is producing this error in line 5:13: Syntax error at input 'end of line without line continuation'; Below the piece of code:

```
//@version=5
strategy("MF chat3 Supertrend Strategy", overlay=true)
import talib

// SuperTrend Function
atrPeriod = input(title="ATR Period", type=input.integer, defval=10)
atrMultiplier = input(title="ATR Multiplier", type=input.float, defval=3.0)
atrMethod = input(title="ATR Method", type=input.string, options=["RMA", "EMA", "SMA"], defval="RMA")
```

Goal: Compiling the pine code in the Tradeview strategy tester